# jquery, focus will disappear when clicking the blank area on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

focus() of item will disappear when clicking the blank area.

code likes

```
$("#cusArea").find("#" + cusId).focus();
```

I hope if the item is not changed, the highlight will be focused on the current item whatever clicking on the blank space or right click ....

how to workaround for this problem?

Comment: what do you mean by `if the item is not changed`

Comment: `focus` changes based on what the Client `focus`es on.

Comment: I meant the anchor item selected is not changed, whatever you click blank space or right-click, the focus will be kept on the anchor item selected.

Comment: Where is your conditional code?

Answer (score 1):

That is default behavior of events.but there are some workarounds too which has some side effects which you have to look into.

for example if your intention is to keep focus on some input and want's to keep focus until some value entered into it then we can use .

```
$("body").click(function(e){

if(!$("#inp1").val()){
 e.preventDefault();
   $("#inp1").focus();
  return;
}
```

hope you can do more trials on this and get good knowledge over events.

[jsbin code sample](http://jsbin.com/dipuyi/1)

Comment: also you do not need to use click on body should try blur event on input

Answer (score 0):

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bs0kzk5s/2/)

that should work

```
var _value = null;
```

// need to to declare it outside on function wrapper

```
$(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.

    _value = $('#test').val();
     //save start value of input

    $('#test').blur(function (e) {
        //catching blur event of input
        var _this = $(this);
        //saving jq object of element

        //compering stored value to current input value
        if (_value == _this.val()) {
            //values are same
            e.preventDefault();
            //set fosuc back on element
            _this.focus();
        } else {
            //in other case 
            // save new value
            // not sure i you need this
            _value = _this.val();
        }

    })
//set focus on input at the start
    $('#test').focus();
})
```